# Does a router's ARP table contain the MAC address for all destination IPs?

Tags: networking, router, routing, switch, arp

Let's say we have the following configuration.

```
WAN - Router -------------------- Switch --------- Client
                       |                     |
   Multiple switches connected to router     |
                                   Multiple Clients connected to each switch
```

When the router receives a packet, then the router would have to lookup its ARP table to find the appropriate MAC that corresponds to the IP address to create the frame to send off to the switch.

However, let's assume among the many switches there is a switch, let's call it `S1`, that is only connected to clients with IPs in range 123.123.123.0/24. This would mean that we can set up a routing rule at the router to route all traffic in range of 123.123.123.0/24 to be sent to the interface that leads to `S1`.

We can see that when routing, the router wouldn't need a routing table of every client. However, the ARP table would need a table of every client. That seems very inefficient to me. Is this really how it works? Wouldn't it make more sense for the Switch to be able to have its own ARP table so that you only need to look up a subset of clients?

To me, it would make more sense for the router here not to build a frame and send the packet that lacks L2 info to the switch, and then the switch builds a frame if the frame is incomplete. I know that switches operating in L2 does not want to look at the IP addresses, but I don't understand why it's designed that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly inefficient, as long as the clients all fit in each switch's MAC table – the CAM "content-addressed memory" is pretty good at finding the MAC table entry efficiently.

> Wouldn't it make more sense for the Switch to be able to have its own ARP table so that you only need to look up a subset of clients?

Then it would be a router, literally. What you suggest *is* often done, just with actual IP routing – the first router directs the packet to the MAC address of the second, knowing that the /24 is there.

Your example is inefficient because you designed it that way. A network isn't inherently limited to one router, and a router isn't limited to one internal network, so you don't have to have one huge subnet if you can avoid it – you can have the /24 as a completely separate subnet behind its own router if you want, or a VLAN managed by the same router but separated at L2 using 802.1Q tags.

(Where a "home" router has one LAN interface going into an integrated switch, enterprise routers have *many* independent interfaces to route between.)

On the other hand, when you really need efficiency, there's a third way to forward packets: label switching, such as MPLS. It allows an ingress router to pre-select the L2 path through a network, with the interior routers/switches only doing lookups in small label tables.

Comment: It's 6am so this is going to look a bit incoherent when I wake up

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "Then it would be a router, literally. What you suggest is often done, just with actual IP routing – the first router directs the packet to the MAC address of the second, knowing that the /24 is there." Right, but to me that means I should put a router in front of every switch, which still makes me question why switches are designed as they are. It seems like L3 switches that also have its own IP and MAC addresses (I know not all of them do) are just strictly better than L2 switches other than cost.

Comment: When you say "as long as the clients all fit in each switch's MAC table", does this mean the ARP table in the router is somehow communicating with a switch's MAC table?

Comment: "It seems like L3 switches that also have its own IP and MAC addresses (I know not all of them do)" Actually it seems like L3 switches that don't have its own IP and MAC addresses are only like that if you configure it not to do L3 routing

Comment: "L3 switches" are routers, so they _do_ have their own IP address and MAC address. (Specifically, they have configurable hardware that can either perform L2 switching or L3 routing. They don't use their MAC address for switched ports but they do for routing.) No, the two tables don't communicate at all, they just both get populated in somewhat similar ways (automatic learning).

Comment: "No, the two tables don't communicate at all, they just both get populated in somewhat similar ways" So then, I'm not sure how the MAC table or CAM table of the switch is relevant in the fact that the router has to look up an ARP table that contains every clients. But regardless, like you said, they probably do act pretty similar and so they prob have optimized hardware and table layouts like the CAM table. Nevertheless it seems weird and unnecessary extra work to me.

Comment: I guess it seems weird and unnecessary if you assume the system was _designed_ for switches and for IP-over-Ethernet from day one. The point though, is that it wasn't. Switches were a much later invention after Ethernet had been originally built on top of "dumb" hardware (such as completely passive coax cables) for a long time, _and_ after Ethernet had been in use to carry quite a few different network protocols (some of which were more widespread than IP) – they're already an optimization of Ethernet's old behavior but deliberately without changing the fundamentals.

Comment: There were other systems that had been designed for a single protocol from day one, e.g. ATM was popular for a period of time and had only a single kind of "ATM switch" device that was like a router and a switch combined. (It had several other downsides though and never became anything more than carrier for IP-over-ATM before dying off. It did directly inspire several IPv6 features though.) There are quite a few downsides to Ethernet switches being IP-agnostic but the flexibility still tends to win every time (especially as new protocols get added).

Comment: And as for the efficiency of ARP table lookups in a router – again, if that becomes an issue, split up the subnet into smaller ones. Replacing a switch with a second router will literally make it so that the first router only needs to have one ARP entry (for the second gateway). In most cases, there is already a need to do it for other reasons anyway (separate LANs or VLANs having different firewall rules, different DHCP pools, etc).

Comment: (One more reason is host mobility – sometimes you _don't_ want all hosts in that /24 to be limited to a specific switch; you want them to be able to exist anywhere in the building, or sometimes even anywhere in the campus... Though that's maybe more of an unfortunate result of IP addresses being both identifiers and locators, with things like Mobile-IP and LISP trying (unsuccessfully) to fix that design issue.)